# initializer-list constructor causing ambiguity with rvalue constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting an error in Visual Studio C++11 when trying to use initializer-lists as shown in the following code

```
template <typename T>
struct TestArray
{
  TestArray(std::initializer_list<T> list) {}
  TestArray(TestArray<T> &&rval) {} // This causes an error
};

struct TestPair
{
  TestPair(int a, int b) {}
};
```

When I declare:

```
TestArray<TestPair> blah({ { 1, 2 } });
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'TestArray<TestPair>'
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload     resolution was ambiguous
```

If I remove the rvalue constructor, it works fine. Why is there some kind of ambiguity between the initializer-list and the rvalue constructor here?

Comment: Remove the outer parens: `blah{{1,2}}`.

Comment: Could someone please explain the generalized circumstances in which the ({ }) syntax breaks? I.e. it seems to work in 90% of cases, and I see a lot of people using it. What are the generalized rules under which it is considered wrong?

Comment: Works with both gcc/clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9e5b517982677c3).

Comment: Your code is not actually wrong, your VS is wrong, The latest and greatest version compiles it, as do gcc, clang, icl...

Answer (score 0):

You test is wrong, you shouldn't have outer `()`'s, more like:

```
TestArray<TestPair> blah{{1, 2}};
```